# Consulta Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel-eloquent

Como gero a consulta abaixo com `Eloquent`, em vista de que o `Group By` da erro no `Eloquent`.

```
SELECT
  otimibus_gps.positions.id,
  otimibus_gps.positions.deviceid,
  otimibus_gps.positions.devicetime,
  otimibus_gps.positions.latitude,
  otimibus_gps.positions.longitude
FROM
  otimibus_gps.positions
WHERE deviceid in ('1','2')
GROUP BY deviceid
ORDER BY devicetime DESC
```

Comment: Qual o erro que está sendo apresentado quando você tenta fazer a consulta pelo Eloquent?

Comment: Quanto coloco o select e a expressão acima ele retorna vazio quando deveria retornar no mínimo 2 linhas e quando uso o ->groupBy da erro Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1

Comment: @CarlosAlexandreRRamos, coloque o que você consegiu fazer e coloca o erro na sua resposta por favor e explique qual agrupamento você precisa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para gerar essa consulta você tem 2 formas de faze-la.

No caso eu vou assumir que o nome da sua tabela é positions mesmo, mas o que tentarei te explicar vale para qualquer tabela que você quer usar da base de dados.

Usando a biblioteca DB ou o Elonquent do Laravel, ambos são excelentes mas cada um funciona um pouco de diferente, mas a finalidade é a mesma.

Caso você queira usar o Elonquent você precisa criar uma model.

Para criar models, oriento usar o assistente do artisan do próprio laravel, você abre um prompt de comando e vai até a pasta do seu projeto e digite:

```
php artisan make:model Positions
```

A model que será criada ficar na sua pasta **app**.

Com a model criada você entra nela e define a tabela que sera usada no banco através da linha de código:

```
protected $table = "positions"
```

Caso você não possua os campos **created_at, updated_at e deleted_at** na sua tabela do tipo **timestamps** (estou considerando que você está usando MySQL como base de dados) você tem que desativar o timestamps dela (estou implicando que você irá o elonquent do laravel para inserções, edições e assim por diante). E para fazer isso ainda dentro da sua model você precisa digitar a seguinte linha de código:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Esse passo já está pronto, agora vamos usar o seu enloquent.

Primeiramente você precisar configurar sua model dentro do seu controller caso você não queira ficar batendo cabeça com referências.

Então você vai pegar e colocar o seguinte uma linha abaixo de algum termo **use**

```
use App\Positions;
```

Pronto, sua controle já está referênciada com sua model.

Agora vamos criar sua query dentro do método, existem 2 formas de fazer, aparentemente não há diferença, mas tecnicamente tem diferenças em relação a memória e etc, mas não é o foco da resposta então deixo isso como curiosidade para suas pesquisas.

Para você fazer a query ficaria assim do jeito 1:

```
$positions = new Positions();
$positions = $positions->select('id', 'deviceid', 'devicetime', 'latitude', 'longitude')
    ->whereIn('deviceid', [1, 2])
    ->groupBy('id', 'deviceid', 'devicetime', 'latitude', 'longitude')
    ->orderBy('devicetime', DESC)
    ->get();
```

E a segunda forma é como o Virgilio Novic disse acima, mas você não pode esquecer de acima após a declaração do namespace da sua controller colocar o **use DB**

Basicamente é assim, não é muito dificil e nem nada, você não disse qual era a versão do laravel que está usando, logo assumo que é a mais recente, aconselho dá uma boa lida na documentação que ela é bem fácil e simples compreensão.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5

Comment: Desde já agradeço, tentei assim ontem mais ao invés de me retornar o ultimo registro do Id1 e Id2, ele está me trazendo todos em ordem decrescente quanto a versão e 5.4

Comment: Consegui dessa forma Obrigado Obrigado mesmo
$dados = Position::select('deviceid', 'devicetime', 'latitude', 'longitude')
                              ->whereIn('deviceid', [1, 2])
                              ->groupBy('deviceid')
                              ->orderBy('devicetime', 'DESC')
                              ->get();

Comment: Que bom que você conseguiu, fico feliz em ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar utilizar da seguinte maneira:

```
Model::select('id', 'deviceid', 'devicetime', 'latitude', 'longitude')
    ->whereIn('deviceid', [1, 2])
    ->groupBy('id', 'deviceid', 'devicetime', 'latitude', 'longitude')
    ->orderBy('devicetime', DESC)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Acho que estamos no caminho certo mais ele trouxe todas as posições desagrupadas, exemplo precisa que ele traga apenas uma linha ora cada is inserido no WhereIn

Comment: Desculpe não consegui compreender, pode dar mais detalhes? Assim fica mais fácil lhe ajudar.

Comment: preciso de um resultado assim:

Comment: {
    "id": 389,
    "deviceid": 2,
    "latitude": -22.7306,
    "longitude": -42.943278333333
}

{
    "id": 388,
    "deviceid": 1,
    "latitude": -22.7306,
    "longitude": -42.943278333333
}

Comment: e ele esta me trazendo todos os registros

Comment: Um device poderá ter mais de um registro nesta mesma tabela? Porque o correto com esta query será ele trazer somente os Devices 1 e 2 que estão no whereIn.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'otimibus_gps.positions.devicetime

Comment: Não sei se é a forma correta de proceder, mas altere no `config/database.php` no array de sua conexão para `'strict' => false` e teste novamente deixando no groupBy somente o `deviceid`